# How to define in ANTLR4 a string with escaping boundary (like multipart mimetype)?

Tags: antlr4

In my grammar, I want to allow 2 syntax for a string:

1. The classical way `"my \"string\""`, no problem here.
2. A new approach with an arbitrary escaping boundary : `|"my "string"|"`, `|x"my |"string"|x"`. The objective is to keep the string content without any escaping and never have something like `a &amp;&amp; b` when a js fragment is in a x(ht)ml file for example.

In the spirit, I'm looking to express something like :

```
'|' {$Boundary} '"' {AnyCharSequenceExcept('|' $Boundary '"')} '|' {$Boundary} '"'
```

I understand I can't do it in standard ANTLR4. Is it possible to do it with actions ?

Comment: In the first case, the start and end is the sequence  `|"`: a `"` is then allowed in the string without escaping.

Comment: In the second case (`|x"my |"string"|x"`) the start and end is `|x"`: a sequence `|"` is then also allowed in the string without escaping. The idea is you (or your editor) ensure that the start and end of the string sequence is never present in the content: so the string content has never to be escaped. `|xyz"` is an other valid starting and closing sequence string.

Comment: Ah, OK. I thought `|"my "string"|"` was your entire opening-tag, but it's just `|"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do that:

```
lexer grammar DemoLexer;

@members {

def ahead(self, steps):
    """
    Returns the next `steps` characters ahead in the character-stream or None if
    there aren't `steps` characters ahead aymore
    """
    text = ""
    for n in range(1, steps + 1):
        next = self._input.LA(n)
        if next == Token.EOF:
            return None
        text += chr(next)
    return text

def consume_until(self, open_tag):
    """
    If we get here, it means the lexer matched an opening tag, and we now consume as
    much characters until we match the corresponsing closing tag
    """
    while True:
        ahead = self.ahead(len(open_tag))
        if ahead == None:
            raise Exception("missing '{}' close tag".format(open_tag))
        if ahead == open_tag:
            break
        self._input.consume()

    # Be sure to consume the end_tag, which has the same character count as `open_tag`
    for n in range(0, len(open_tag)):
        self._input.consume()

}

STRING
 : '|' ~'"'* '"' {self.consume_until(self.text)}
 ;

SPACES
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;

OTHER
 : .
 ;
```

If you generate the lexer from the grammar above and run the following (Python) script:

```py
from antlr4 import *
from DemoLexer import DemoLexer


source = """
foo |x"my |"string"|x" bar
"""

lexer = DemoLexer(InputStream(source))
stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
stream.fill()

for token in stream.tokens[:-1]:
    print("{0:<25} '{1}'".format(DemoLexer.symbolicNames[token.type], token.text))
```

the following will be printed to your console:

```
OTHER                     'f'
OTHER                     'o'
OTHER                     'o'
STRING                    '|x"my |"string"|x"'
OTHER                     'b'
OTHER                     'a'
OTHER                     'r'
```